# Is there a way to shorten this code? C# winforms

Tags: c#

I'm studying MDI Form in windows form and I'm playing with this simple application:
[image]

Each `ToolStripMeniItem` calls a single instance of a particular form, but as you can see (please see my code) my code is repetitive for each ToolStripMeniItem, how can I shorten this?

```
        public static Form IsFormAlreadyOpen(Type FormType)
        {
            foreach (Form OpenForm in Application.OpenForms)
            {
                if (OpenForm.GetType() == FormType)
                    return OpenForm;
            }
            return null;
        }

        private void form1ToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Form1 f1 = null;
            if (IsFormAlreadyOpen(typeof(Form1)) == null)
            {
                f1 = new Form1();
                f1.MdiParent = this;
                f1.Show();
            }
            else
            {
                Form selectedForm = IsFormAlreadyOpen(typeof(Form1));
                foreach (Form OpenForm in this.MdiChildren)
                {
                    if (OpenForm == selectedForm)
                    {
                        if (selectedForm.WindowState == FormWindowState.Minimized)
                        {
                            selectedForm.WindowState = FormWindowState.Normal;
                        }
                        selectedForm.Select();
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        private void form2ToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Form2 f2 = null;
            if (IsFormAlreadyOpen(typeof(Form2)) == null)
            {
                f2 = new Form2();
                f2.MdiParent = this;
                f2.Show();
            }
            else
            {
                Form selectedForm = IsFormAlreadyOpen(typeof(Form2));
                foreach (Form OpenForm in this.MdiChildren)
                {
                    if (OpenForm == selectedForm)
                    {
                        if (selectedForm.WindowState == FormWindowState.Minimized)
                        {
                            selectedForm.WindowState = FormWindowState.Normal;
                        }
                        selectedForm.Select();
                    }
                }
            }
            // and so on... for the other ToolStripMeniItem
        }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[A generic function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms379564%28VS.80%29.aspx) is a function that will work with a set of types that will be defined by the caller

so instead of 
`int doubleIt(int a) { return a*2; }` 
you can say
`T doubleIt<T>(T a){ return a*2; }`

this means you can define one function that can be called like this:

```
int intResult = doubleIt(...pass in a int..);
double doubleResult = doubleIt(...pass in a double..);
float floatResult = doubleIt(...pass in a float..);
```

So for your code you create a method that takes the form type you're creating as a value for T.

**However the compiler doesn't know that T is a form and that you can call new on it, so you must contrain the types that can be passed as T with the where clause saying T must be a form and must a constructor that you can access**

You therefore replace the core functionality with a generic function that is specialised to the type of f1 that you need.

so instead of `Form f1 = null;` you have a generic type that you pass in `T f1 = null;`

```
private void ClickEvent<T>(object sender, EventArgs e) where T: Form, new() {
            T f1 = null;
    .
    .
    .
 }
```

Then call this method from the real event handlers

```
private void form1ToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)       {
            ClickEvent<Form1>(sender, e)
        }

        private void form2ToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
           ClickEvent<Form1>(sender, e) 
        }
```

So you end up with something like:

```
public static Form IsFormAlreadyOpen(Type FormType)
{
    foreach (Form OpenForm in Application.OpenForms)
    {
        if (OpenForm.GetType() == FormType)
            return OpenForm;
    }
    return null;
}

private void ClickEvent<T>(object sender, EventArgs e) where T: Form, new() 
    {
    T f1 = null;
    if (IsFormAlreadyOpen(typeof(T)) == null)
    {
        f1 = new T();
        f1.MdiParent = this;
        f1.Show();
    }
    else
    {
        Form selectedForm = IsFormAlreadyOpen(typeof(T));
        foreach (Form OpenForm in this.MdiChildren)
        {
            if (OpenForm == selectedForm)
            {
                if (selectedForm.WindowState == FormWindowState.Minimized)
                {
                    selectedForm.WindowState = FormWindowState.Normal;
                }
                selectedForm.Select();
            }
        }
    }
}

    private void form1ToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)       {
        ClickEvent<Form1>(sender, e)
    }

private void form2ToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
   ClickEvent<Form1>(sender, e) 
}
```

Extra: If you can use Linq, then something like this.

```
  using System.Linq;

             public static Form IsFormAlreadyOpen(Type FormType)        {       
                return Application.OpenForms.Where( f => f.GetType() == FormType).FirstOrDefault();
            }

            private void ClickEvent<T>(object sender, EventArgs e) where T: Form, new() 
            {
                T selectedForm = IsFormAlreadyOpen(typeof(T); 
                if (selectedForm == null)             {
                    (new T() { MdiParent = this; }).Show()
                }
                else {  
                    this.MdiChildren.Where(o => o == selectedForm).ForEach(
                        openForm => { 
                            selectedForm.WindowState = (selectedForm.WindowState == FormWindowState.Minimized) ? FormWindowState.Normal : selectedForm.WindowState;
                            openForm.Select();
                        }
                    );
                }
            }
            private void form1ToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)       {
                ClickEvent<Form1>(sender, e)
            }

            private void form2ToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
               ClickEvent<Form2>(sender, e) 
            }
```

There are other things you can do to shorten this code, however the use of generics and linq will be the most effective.

Comment: I think that's a bit too advanced, obviously the OP is learning about winforms... this seems a bit overkill...

Comment: though it's what i want, a reusable method.

Comment: @Preet ~ I like how you did that, it works out a little better than the clever method. And the use of the ClickEvent<T> for generics is nice. I would have put a note in your body about it being Generics since he's learning, so he would identify the <T> (`aka` things I wish I had known when I was learning this stuff)

Comment: sir, just a question.. in your code above(not the linq one) it seems the the other form will not open because of this: private void ClickEvent<T>(object sender, EventArgs e) where T: Form, new() 
    {
    T f1 = null;
    if (IsFormAlreadyOpen(typeof(Form1)) == null)
    {
        f1 = new Form1();
        f1.MdiParent = this;
        f1.Show();
    }---- i am right?

Comment: @yonan2236 ~ Can you give the error your getting? That should work if you followed his code and used this block: `private void form1ToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) { ClickEvent<Form1>(sender, e); }` ... at least, it should work if you change `where T: Form, new()` to `where T: Form, Form1, Form3 ... etc`

Comment: For that matter, remove the `where T: Form, new()` block (or any derivatives) altogether, until you learn how those constraints work

Comment: @Preet Sangha: thanks for explaining very well, I understand it now... thanks sir :)

Comment: though i have an error on this code: if (IsFormAlreadyOpen(typeof(T)) == null)
    {
        f1 = new Form1();
        f1.MdiParent = this;
        f1.Show();
    }

Comment: error: Cannot implicitly convert type 'OneInstance.Form1' to 'T'

Comment: sorry replace f1 = new Form1();  with f1 = new T();, I've changed the answer

Answer (score 2):

Might be easier to use the '**Tag**' property of the MenuItem class and use that instead, and dynamically build up the menuitems adding it into the MenuStrip, and using a singular Click Event handler for ***all*** menu items, then it's a matter of finding out which tag was used, for an example you can set the tag to the Form like this

```
menuItem = new MenuItem("Form 1");
menuItem.Tag = Form1;
menuItem.Click += new EventHandler(frmMDI_FormHandler_Click);
frmMDI.MenuStrip.Add(menuItem);
```

Comment: This is what I was thinking, adding onclick handlers dynamically. I think you could even override the EventHandler to pass a third value using this method, so you could pass in the form type from code. ... also, +1 for making it so the menu item can be added in the codebehind (potentially being loaded from an XML file for full customizability? :p )

Comment: you would repeat the block `menuItem = new ... ... frmMDI.MenuStirp.Add(menuItem);` for each item you wanted to add in your form onload (but you might have a situation where you need to limit how often this block runs ... just a consideration)

Comment: +1 although using the `Tag` property of a control can be dicey, if someone or something ends up trying to use `Tag` for a different purpose. I'd probably create a custom class that inherits from `MenuItem` and adds a property specific to this usage.

Answer (score 2):

I was thinking of factoring out the common functionality into a generic method.  It does use generics and `Activator.CreateInstance`, but other than that, the code below is almost all the OP's code, just refactored.

```
private void form1ToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    OpenForm<Form2>();
}

private void OpenForm<T>() where T : Form
{
    T form = null;

    if (IsFormAlreadyOpen(typeof(T)) == null)
    {
        form = Activator.CreateInstance<T>();
        form.MdiParent = this;
        form.Show();
    }
    else
    {
        Form selectedForm = IsFormAlreadyOpen(typeof(T));
        foreach (Form OpenForm in this.MdiChildren)
        {
            if (OpenForm == selectedForm)
            {
                if (selectedForm.WindowState == FormWindowState.Minimized)
                {
                    selectedForm.WindowState = FormWindowState.Normal;
                }
                selectedForm.Select();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: except the typos? (eeek, ohnoes) ~~ Also, doesn't hurt to go ahead and continue to pass `object sender, EventArgs e` altho that would be bloat if it wasn't needed. More of a note to @yonan

Comment: this code works for me. and It's quite understandable... thanks sir Adrift

Answer (score 0):

hackish way to shorten this code (I don't think this is what you mean tho :p )

Also note: "IsXYZ(val)" implies a bool response... think about that. Try "GetOpenForm(Type FormType)"

```
public static Form IsFormOpen(Type FormType) {
  foreach (Form OpenForm in Application.OpenForms) 
    if (OpenForm.GetType() == FormType)
      return OpenForm;
  return null;
}
```

Note that it helps to define "shorten the code" ... do you only mean deduping the keystrokes needed to generate new code for new cases?

Also, note that combining the answers of Preet and Tommie gives you a way to look at `sender` and get the type that's calling your method, allowing you to customize logic there. The funky logic of checking for each form by type is what's causing the code to seem overly convoluted. If there were another way to identify the open windows, that could work out in your favor.